# My blog, under ssl

Tags: ssl, https

I want to have all my content from my blog distributed in a ssl encrypted connection (meaning, I want to go https)

What are the drawbacks with respect to an unencrypted, "regular" http connection?

Comment: *I have a certificate and I want to use it for something* -- Are you sure it's a certificate you can use for web hosting? That's not something you get by accident...

Comment: It was included in my web host upgraded package. I am using it to encrypt openid negotiation now, but I'd like to put everything under ssl.

Comment: What possible reason could you have for using https?  Are you trying to stop people from reading your blog?  That's sort of the opposite of why most people make a blog.

Comment: @Paul, why would that stop people. Even the browser in my very old mobile phone supports HTTPS.

Comment: I don't see people being stopped by amazon's ssl page....

Comment: It's public information, so why take steps to prevent people from sniffing the packets?  And in return for preventing people from sniffing this public information, you've made your blog slower to load, more CPU intensive, and works on fewer browsers.

Comment: @Paul: because, as I said, I am tired of hearing people saying that if you use encryption you are doing illegal stuff. I would actually encourage anyone else to do the same, but for now I'd settle with mine.

Answer (score 4):

- Slightly more server CPU usage (only relevant for big sites)
- The first SSL handshake may take a second or two (further page loads can skip it)
- One certificate per IP address (because they're exchanged before sending any data - so the `Host` HTTP header cannot be used.

  - [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) allows using multiple certificates per IP address, but not all HTTP servers and clients`*` support it yet. (For example, on Debian 5 with Apache2, you need to switch to `mod_gnutls`, or compile `mod_ssl` manually.)
- If your certificate is self-signed, it can become really annoying for visitors.
- Same if any of your images/stylesheets/scripts are loaded over plain HTTP.

---

*(`*` `wget` and `curl` can't really be called "browsers")*

Comment: Although wget and curl may not be called "browsers", IE on WinXP usually does.

Comment: Regarding ["slightly more"](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html).

Answer (score 2):

The only two I can think of is it slightly slower and makes a higher load on the server.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend what your blog actually does. For example, are you including images from other sites? Are https-URIs for those images available? If not, you will end up with browsers complaining about insecure content.

May I ask why you are considering https?

Comment: because I have a certificate and I want to use it for something. Also, I am tired of hearing people saying that only banks and illegal stuff use encryption.

Comment: good point for the included stuff. hmmmm.... it can be annoying I guess. any opinion about this point ?

Comment: IMHO it's a real show stopper. People don't want to be annoyed by stuff like that. Of course, you can always host this stuff on your site (I guess).

Comment: no, I embed images from the pedia... this is annoying. :(

Comment: So I have a certificate and don't know what to do with it ... so sad.

Comment: If by "the pedia" you mean Wikipedia, then try https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/

Comment: Hmm. I get a timeout when trying to access this URL.

Comment: me too. I also have youtube videos. It is clear that I cannot act as a proxy for all these sites...

Comment: Will it pop up the warning if I add the content dynamically via javascript ?

Comment: Well, I hope you will get a warning. If you don't, report it as a bug in your browser ;-)